# Unable to schedule expo notifications every 3 days

Tags: reactjs, notifications, expo, native, schedule

I'm working on a project where i want to schedule notifications every X days.
here is the part where i schedule notifications :

```
let notificationId = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
        content: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
            data: null,
        },
        trigger: { day: freq, repeats: true },   
    });
```

I tried with

```
        trigger: { hour: freq * 24, repeats: true },
```

But every time i get this error :
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failed to schedule the notification. Trigger of type: calendar is not supported on Android.]

I know some people will maybe say it's because i try it on emulator but it should still work and to be sure i try on my phone too and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const trigger = await Notifications.getNextTriggerDateAsync({
                channelId: DECKS_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, 
                hour: 20,
                minute: 0,
                repeats: true,
                //seconds: 2,
            })
```

then

```
let notificationId = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        data: null,
    },
    trigger   
});
```

There are so many types of SchedulabeNotificationTriggers. The one i showed you is for daily. You can check more in this link
[Expo Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/notifications/#schedulablenotificationtriggerinput)

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.